# Place div next to or under in stock

Tags: magento2.3, layout, xml

How can I place a div between in stock and sku using xml for custom block.

I can only seem to place it after sku.

```
<body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku">
            <block class="Stock\Qty\Block\LeftQty" name="catalog.product.view.stock"
                   before="product.info.stock.sku" template="Dolphin_MyModule::leftqty.phtml" cacheable="false"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
```

[image: Product View Page]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with css

Inside the **product-info-stock-sku** div, which is the parent div of the stock and sku you need to place your custom div inside this parent div

After that, add custom css

```
.stock available {
    -webkit-order: 1;
}
.product attribute sku {
    -webkit-order: 3;
}
.your_custom_div_class {
    -webkit-order: 2;
}
.product-info-main .product-info-stock-sku {
    display: grid;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Hope this will work for you :)

Comment: This works for in between IN STOCK and SKU. If I wanted to place it to the left or right of IN STOCK how would I achieve this.

Comment: If it works then please give up-vote. The answer I gave was for your original question, to show custom text in between **In Sotck** and **SKU**. but you want to show left or right the **In Stock** then you need to override the main class for the sku and stock parent div which is **.product-info-main .product-info-stock-sku** you have to write your own css for that

Answer (score 0):

you first go to your theme directory app/design/frontend/Mytheme/Default/Magento_Catalog/layout/ and create new file catalog_product_view.xml

```
<body>
    <move element="catalog.product.view.stock" destination="product.info.stock.sku" before="product.info.sku"/>
</body>
```

here => catalog.product.view.stock => your XML add name

I am also adding a custom block you want too. so please check the screenshot below for more information.[image]

For your more information "**In stock**" is get below file

vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

and this file call in XML

/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_simple.xml

if any issue then ask me again.